# Laravel migration relation

Tags: php, laravel

I have problems with laravel migrations. I want to set a relation between 2 tables. For example, I have table users and table products, and in the products table, I have user_owner column so I can specify the user like so:

Users table

```
$table->bigIncrements('id');
```

Product table

```
$table->integer('user_owner');
$table->foreign('user_owner')->references('id')->on('users');
```

But every time when I want to migrate this table I have error like:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `ecomet_html`.`#sql-3c38_b9` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `products` add constraint `products_store_id_foreign` foreign key (`store_id`) references `stores` (`id`))
```

Why am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your error also indicates the error in store_id foreign. where you have to set the store_id foreign key in product table??

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if products table is alphabeticaly before user table (migration .php files). Artisan is taking them one by one and possibly it takes products before users and then database cannot detect users table because its not created yet.
2. Check keys formats! Lenghts of both IDs from Users and Products are different. Try (product table):`$table->bigInteger('user_owner'); or $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_owner'); or $table->bigInteger('user_owner')->unsigned();`
3. Another suggestion is to do: `$table->foreign('user_owner')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');`, db engine could require onDelete argument

Comment: I know, actually, this table is migrating last, and users are migrated first.

Comment: Can you provide migration definitions?

Answer (score 0):

give this a try.

Update your user_owner from:

```
    $table->integer('user_owner');
```

To:

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_owner');
```